# Javafx grid pane..cannot add rows dynamically..without getting shrink

Tags: java, javafx, dynamic, fxml, gridpanel

I want to add ui nodes dynamically to a gridapanes row without shrinking ..and instead of shrinking gridpane should enable scrolling (grid pane is in a scroll pane)..but neither of them is happening...

All I am attempting is to create a event calender with ability to view events of whole month as days in the top row (so at least 30 columns).

Controller class

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;


import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {
    public GridPane gridPane;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
            VBox box = new VBox();
            Label label = new Label(Integer.toString(i));
            label.setMinHeight(50);
            label.prefHeight(50);
            label.setMaxHeight(50);
            gridPane.setGridLinesVisible(true);
            label.setStyle("-fx-background-color:yellow;");
            box.getChildren().add(label);
            box.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            gridPane.add(box, 0, i);
        }

        Label labe2 = new Label("HelloWorld");
        labe2.setMinHeight(80);
        gridPane.add(labe2, 0, 15);
    }
}
```

Really need help

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0"
            prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
            fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <children>
        <AnchorPane layoutX="39.0" layoutY="15.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0"
                    AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <children>
                <ScrollPane fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true" pannable="true" prefHeight="239.0" prefWidth="331.0"
                            AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0"
                            AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                    <content>
                        <GridPane fx:id="gridPane" prefHeight="239.0" prefWidth="331.0">
                            <columnConstraints>
                                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
                                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
                                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
                                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
                                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
                                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
                                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
                            </columnConstraints>
                            <rowConstraints>
                                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                            </rowConstraints>
                        </GridPane>
                    </content>
                </ScrollPane>
            </children>
        </AnchorPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: You probably need to use some other `Node`. `ListView`, I am guessing.

Comment: For what should I use list view?? Xan you explain a bit..

Comment: I was just guessing. Research the different `Nodes` and determine which one would be better for your situation.

Comment: From the look of your image, I am guessing `ListView` or `TableView`.

Comment: @Sedrick .which node should i replace...VBox insdie the cell of grid ???can you be more specific..so that i can work it out...thank you for helping out..

Comment: You might want to set your row's `minHeight` to match the `prefHeight`. Otherwise they will always shrink to 10px before enabling the scroll pane.

Comment: @Zephyr doesnt work ...dont know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved this issue..instead of creating the grid pan in scene builder ..just create the grid using code and set constrains through code...try to create constrains early as possible in your execution order of the code..

didn't work out for me using scene builder created grid pane

Answer (score 0):

Your `GridPane` rows all have a `minHeight` of `10.0`. This means they will always shrink to that size before utilizing the `ScrollPane`.

Change the `minHeight` for each row to `-Infinity`, which basically makes it match your `prefHeight`:

```
<RowConstraints minHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
```

Alternatively, in order to set these contraints programatically in your controller, add a new `RowConstraints` after adding the `VBox`:

```
gridPane.getRowConstraints().add(new RowConstraints(30));
```

Comment: not helping ...program wont even run after changing the FXML attribute..Raising the minHeight doesnt fix the issue

Comment: Running your exact  code, after making the changes I suggested, runs correctly here. All rows remain the exact same height and Scene Builder opens the file just fine. Are you sure you didn't accidentally change something else as well?

Comment: didnt do any changes ..except the one you suggested ..ill give it a shot again..thank you